# Как быстро циклом обойти строку из 20к символов, сравнивая элементы внутри цикла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дается 2 строки и нужно поменять в первой строке 2 любых элемента местами и если она будет равна второй строке, возвращаем true.

Например, s = "aabc", goal = "aacb". Можно поменять местами в строке s "b" и "c", и строка станет равна строке goal.

Проблема заключается в том, что строки бывают длинные, по 20к символов, и по времени не прохожу. Вот пример моего кода.

```
def buddyStrings(s, goal):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(len(s)):
            if i != j:
                l = list(s)
                l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i]
                l = ''.join(l)
                if l == goal:
                    return True
    return False
```

А вот, собственно, и сами строки:

```
# Общая длинна строк 20к символов, после троеточия идут "а"

s = "bcaaaaa..." 

goal = "abcaaaa..."
#Тут вернется false
```

или другой вариант

```
# Также общая длинна строк 20к символов, "а" идут вначале

s = "...aaabc"
goal = "...aaacb"
#тут вернется true
```

Длинные строки даются разные, где то дубли идут в начале, а в конце 3 уникальных значения, могут в середине, то есть просто сделать срез не получится. Также не подходит вариант в set(), так как он оставит только уникальные значения, а, например, строки s = "abab" и goal = "abab" дадут true, а если оставить только уникальные значения, мы получим строку "ab", которая даст false.

Comment: Условие поточнее приведите. Что означает "2 любых элемента "? Причём тут уникальные значения?

Comment: 1. просматривайте сразу обе строки в одном цикле. 2. строку `abc` невозможно превратить в `bca`, поменяв местами лишь две буквы.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: @MBo добавила конкретики

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуем так:

```
def buddyStrings(s, goal):
    if len(s) != len(goal):
        return False
    sd = []
    gd = []
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] != goal[i]:
            sd.append(s[i])
            gd.append(goal[i])
            if len(sd) > 2:
                return False
    return len(sd)==2 and gd[1]==sd[0] and gd[0]==sd[1]

print(buddyStrings("acb", "abc"))
```

Подразумевается, что один обмен обязателен. Если нет,
то

```
return (len(sd)==0) or (len(sd)==2 and gd[1]==sd[0] and gd[0]==sd[1])
```

Comment: Ваш вариант выдает false, вместо true для следующих вариантов строк:
1) s = "aa", goal = "aa"
2) s = "abab", goal = "abab"

Comment: Вы до конца прочитали?

Comment: конечно прочитала. Один обмен обязателен. Но вы правы, второй вывод мне подошел. Я просто немного дополнила изначальное условие.     if len(s) == 1 or len(s) != len(goal) or (len(set(s)) == len(s) and s==goal): return False. Спасибо большое!